# My increment doesn't work (c)

Tags: c, increment

So, I have this code, at end I have an increment for exit when it reaches 4 (4 times wrong value entered), but it doesn't work:

```
int main() {
  int nej;
  printf("1-Triangulo \n");
  printf("2-Division \n");
  printf("3-Menu \n");
  printf("4-Bosque \n");
  printf("0-Salir \n");
  scanf("%d", &nej);
  if (nej == 1) {
    // Ejercicio 1-Triangulo:

    triangulo();
  }

  if (nej == 2) {
    // Ejercicio 2-Division:

    division();
  }

  if (nej == 3) {
    menu();
  }

  if (nej == 4) {
    arboles();
  }

  if (nej == 0) {
    // Salida
    exit(1);
  }

  int nerr = 0;

  while (nej < 0 || nej > 4) {
    nerr++;
    // Contador de error
    if (nerr == 4) {
      exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```

**How to fix this?**

Comment: is the while condition meant to check _nerr_?

Comment: You angry me. I take time to make your question better and you don't care.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a typo inside the while condition

```
while (nej < 0 || nej > 4) {
...
```

should be:

```
while (nerr < 0 || nerr > 4) {
..
```

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize the `int nerr = 0;`  every time when you read,the flow will never reach the exit condition

```
 int main()
 {
int nej;

int nerr = 0; // Keep the counter outside the loop

while (true){//Start a infinite loop here

printf("1-Triangulo \n");
printf("2-Division \n");
printf("3-Menu \n");
printf("4-Bosque \n");
printf("0-Salir \n");
scanf("%d", &nej);


if (nej == 1) {
  // Ejercicio 1-Triangulo:

  triangulo();
}

if (nej == 2) {
  // Ejercicio 2-Division:

  division();
}

if (nej == 3) {
  menu();
}

if (nej == 4) {
  arboles();
}

if (nej == 0) {
  // Salida
  exit(1);
}



while (nej < 0 || nej > 4) {
  nerr++;
  // Contador de error
  if (nerr == 4) {
    exit(1);
  }
}
}
```

Comment: I believe that the declaration of the variable can be anywhere in the code block and its initialization will be performed once per code block. So it is not performed in the execution flow (i.e. every time control passes the declaration). However, the variable will only be known after its point of declaration.

Answer (score 0):

`nej` being the input, and the input being invalid if less than 0 or larger than 4, the correct statement would be:

```
if (nej < 0 || nej > 4) {
```

(and not `while` as `nej` is not changed in the code block).

Answer (score 0):

It have following errors:

- Code should be in the `while` loop
- Variable `nerr` should be declared and initialize outside the `while` loop
- Variable `nerr` should control the `while` loop

**Note:** It is Ok to use multiple `if`. But use of `switch` is much convenient and advisable.

Corrected code is as following:

```
 int main() {
   int nej;
   int nerr = 0;
   while (nerr < 4) {
   printf("1-Triangulo \n");
   printf("2-Division \n");
   printf("3-Menu \n");
   printf("4-Bosque \n");
   printf("0-Salir \n");
   scanf("%d", &nej);

   switch(nej){
   case 1:// Ejercicio 1-Triangulo:
     triangulo();
   break;
   case 2:// Ejercicio 2-Division:
     division();
   break;
   case 3:
     menu();
   break;
   case 4:
     arboles();
   break;
   case 0:// Salida
     exit(1);
   break;
   default: 
     nerr++;
   }
     // Reset 'nerr' if any valid vaue is entered by user
     if ((nej >= 0) && (nej <= 4)) {
       nerr = 0;
     }
   }
 }
```